# How to create new binary column by checking across all rows of a subject?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, google-bigquery

I have a table like as shown below

```
subject_id  Desc  Name   class   BC  FU  PA  VI 
1                Fung     FU      0   1   0  0  
1                Para     PA      0   0   1  0  
1                Viru     VI      0   0   0  1  
1                Para     PA      0   0   1  0  
1             T5 Bacte    BC      1   0   0  0  
1             T6 Bacte    BC      1   0   0  0 
2             T5 Bacte    BC      1   0   0  0
2                Fung     FU      1   0   0  0
```

What I would like to do is create a new column "BC_FU" which will have 1 if the subject has 1 in BC column and FU column. But it shouldn't be looking for in the same row but across all the records of the same subject.

The same logic applies for BC_VI column (another new column) as well

For ex: If you look at subject_id = 1, we can see that he has 1 in BC column at row 5 and 6 whereas he has FU = 1 at row 1. Now we know that subject_id has both BC and FU in this records (from database)

This is what I tried but doesn't help. I am trying to write in BigQuery, so your help to correct or fix this in BigQuery will be helpful

```
select *, 
CASE WHEN (MAX(BC) == 1 AND MAX(FU) == 1) THEN 1
ELSE 0 END AS BC_FU,
CASE WHEN (MAX(BC) == 1 AND MAX(VI) == 1) THEN 1
ELSE 0 END AS BC_VI,
FROM TABLE T
GROUP BY SUBJECT_ID
```

So, I would like to create an output whick looks like below

```
subject_id  Desc  Name  class  BC FU PA VI BC_FU BC_VI
1                 Fungi  FU     0  1  0 0   1     1
1                 Para   PA     0  0  1 0   1     1
1                 Virus  VI     0  0  0 1   1     1 
1                 Para   PA     0  0  1 0   1     1 
1             T5  Bacte  BC     1  0  0 0   1     1
1             T6  Bacte  BC     1  0  0 0   1     1
2             T5  Bacte  BC     1  0  0 0   1     1
2                 Virus  VI     0  1  0 1   1     1
```

Comment: Why is `BC_FU` zero for subject 2?  It has ones in both columns.

Comment: You are right. It has to be 1. Will update now. Good catch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following

```
select t1.*
       ,max(BC) over(partition by subject_id)
        *max(FU) over(partition by subject_id) as BC_FU
       ,max(BC) over(partition by subject_id)
        *max(VI) over(partition by subject_id) as BC_VI
  from your_table t1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select t1.*, tmp.BC_FU, tmp.BC_VI
from your_table t1
join
(
  select subject_id, 
         CASE WHEN MAX(BC) + MAX(FU) = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BC_FU,
         CASE WHEN MAX(BC) + MAX(VI) = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BC_VI
  from your_table
  group by subject_id
) tmp on t1.subject_id = tmp.subject_id
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Upvoted. Will try and keep you posted

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your requirement correctly, you should just be able to use analytic functions here:

```
SELECT *,
    CASE WHEN MAX(BC) OVER (PARTITION BY subject_id) +
              MAX(FU) OVER (PARTITION BY subject_id) = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BC_FU,
    CASE WHEN MAX(BC) OVER (PARTITION BY subject_id) +
              MAX(VI) OVER (PARTITION BY subject_id) = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BC_VI
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY subject_id;
```

This answer avoids the need for an unnecessary subquery.

Answer (score 1):

I've read your question and let me add my solution as well.

```
SELECT  t1.*,
        CASE WHEN (MAX(BC) OVER (PARTITION BY subject_id) +
                 MAX(FU) OVER (PARTITION BY subject_id) ) == 2
             THEN 1
             ELSE 0
             END AS BC_FU
        CASE WHEN (MAX(BC) OVER(PARTITION BY subject_id) +
                  MAX(VI) OVER(PARTITION BY subject_id) ) == 2
             THEN 1
             ELSE 0
             END AS BC_VI
FROM    table as t1
ORDER BY subject_id
```

Here are some tips which I thought might be useful for you:)

- OVER () is sometimes referred to as window function. If you type `SELECT (aggregating function) OVER(PARTITION BY columnA)` you can use the aggregation function but not turning the result into single row at the same time. (Please ignore this if you already know)
- As Mr. Tim already mentioned, it's good to remove unnecessary sub-query (a query inside the other) to increase the readability.
- Be sure to add 'Else 0' in every CASE sentence so as not to make the possibility of causing 'NULL'.

Here, I chose to sum up the maximum value of BC and FU to check if it's 2 or not,
rather than not checking 'intersection' (e.g. max(BC) ==1 AND max(FU) ==1) like Mr.Tim's post.

That is because I thought you would probably add such column as 'BC_FU_VI' in the future, 
when '2' would increase readability that this case sentence is actually trying to convert two columns into a single column.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you solved your problem yet? Let me know if you are in trouble